# SWRevealViewController seque disappears navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift

I implemented [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EFfPT3UeWs) . However with difference, instead of doing my seque from talecell to viewcontroller.I did it from entire tableview to view controller.On click of table row, i call it.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showcheckin", sender: self)
}
```

What happens is that, navigation bar item on top disappears.

Comment: solved the issue, had to connect seque to navigation controller, rather then a view controller.

Answer (score -1):

Please create navigation like this don't use segue.

```
     SWRevealViewController *revealController = self.revealViewController;
        [revealController setFrontViewController:rootViewController2 animated:YES];
 UIStoryboard *storyboard =
    [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    rootViewController2 = [storyboard
                           instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Your_ViewCon_Name"];

    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                     initWithRootViewController:rootViewController2];
    navController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

    [navController setViewControllers:@[ rootViewController2 ] animated:YES];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft
                                           animated:YES];
```